# An "Itzykson-Zuber"-like integral

Tags: matrices, integration, reference-request

I been told that there exists an integration formula, which states (or something of this sort)
$$
\int_{U(N)} dU \det[(\mathbb I+XUYU^{-1})^{-r}\propto \frac{\det(1+x_iy_j)^{N-r-1}]_{i,j}}{\Delta_N(x)\Delta_N(y)},
$$
where $dU$ is the Haar-measure, $X=\text{diag}(x_1,\ldots,x_N)$ is a positive definite diagonal matrix with $x_i\neq x_j$ for $i\neq j$ (similar for $Y$), and
$$
\Delta_N(x)=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq N}(x_i-x_j)
$$
is a Vandermonde determinant.

This is somewhat similar to a [Harish-Chandra-Itzykson-Zuber integral](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/the-harish-chandra-itzykson-zuber-integral-formula/), but I haven't seen this specific kind before. Are anyone familiar with this kind of integrals, and how to solve them? I would be particular interested in references to the literature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Since I found a reference which answers this question (and noone has provided any other solution) I will give a short answer to my own question.*

This type of integrals has been studied in the context of two-matrix models. The integral in question has been discussed in [arXiv:0804.0873](http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.0873) (section 3), while a larger class of integrals has been discussed in [arXiv:0512056 [math-ph]](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0512056) (appendix A).

Answer (score 0):

This statement does not seem to be correct, because if X tends to the zero matrix, the left hand side is well defined but the right hand side is not (notice that HCIZ integral does not suffer from this).

Comment: Ups! I had misunderstood the right hand side. I read it as if the numerator had the determinant of the identity plus something... Sorry

Answer (score 0):

This identity, and others of similar type, are proved explicitly in:
J. Harnad and A. Yu. Orlov, ``Fermionic construction of partition functions for two-matrix models and perturbative Schur function expansions'',
J. Phys. A, 39, 8783--8809 (2006). (Appendix A]

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I presume that this type of integrals dates back to Gross and Richards ( [Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 301 (1987), 781](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1987-301-02/S0002-9947-1987-0882715-2/) , [J. Approx. Theory 59 (1989) 224](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021904589901536) , [Bulletin of AMS 24 (1991) 349](http://cat.inist.fr/?aModele=afficheN&cpsidt=19755511) ), which, more recently, have been extended by Orlov and yourself?